# Dynamic Datatype in SELECT result

Tags: t-sql

This is a scalar query, originally within a function. The result datatype varies, depending on which field I'm intresting of.

In this example, I expect a scalar result of datatype NVARCHAR 'Andy' but got an error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line xx Conversion failed when converting
> the nvarchar value 'Andy' to data type int.

Is there any way to get around this?

```
CREATE TABLE ATable (
  Idf INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Col1 INT,
  Col2 NVARCHAR(255),
)
GO

INSERT INTO Atable (Idf, Col1, Col2) VALUES (1, 75, 'Andy')
INSERT INTO Atable (Idf, Col1, Col2) VALUES (2, 39, 'Pete')
GO

DECLARE @Idf INT = 1
DECLARE @Col NVARCHAR(15) = 'Col2'

SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN @Col='Col1' THEN Col1
    WHEN @Col='Col2' THEN Col2
    ELSE NULL
  END AS MyScalarResultOfDynamicDatatype
FROM ATable
WHERE Idf=@Idf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is really, really necessary... you might use the [`sql_variant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql) data type.

```
CASE
  WHEN @Col='Col1' THEN CAST(Col1 AS SQL_VARIANT)
  WHEN @Col='Col2' THEN CAST(Col2 AS SQL_VARIANT)
END AS MyScalarResultOfDynamicDatatype
```

(Note that you do not specifically need an `ELSE NULL` in your `CASE`-statement. If there is no matching `WHEN`, the result will be `NULL` by default.)

**Edit:**

Based on a question in comment regarding the drawbacks, I would like to refer to the article [Problems Caused by the Use of the SQL_VARIANT Datatype](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/problems-caused-by-use-of-the-sql_variant-datatype), written by somebody under the alias [Phil Factor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62661/phil-factor) ([Redgate Simple Talk](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/author/phil-factor/), [Redgate Blog](https://www.red-gate.com/blog/author/phil-factor), [GitHub](https://github.com/Phil-Factor)).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. And of course, it isn't necessary but the code will  be short,, readable and clean if doing it this way. Is there any serious drawbacks?

Comment: I edited my question to include a reference to an interesting article that points out some drawbacks of using the `sql_variant` data type.